# How to category in select statement

Tags: sql

I have a table (in an Oracle database) just like below:

```
department
----------
Finance
Sales
Programmer
Network Admin
System Support
```

I would like to have the output that look like the table below:

```
department
----------
Finance
Sales
IT (those category other than Finance and Sales will group under 'IT')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE
    WHEN department IN ('Programmer', 'Network Admin', 'System Support') THEN 'IT'
    ELSE department
END
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

That's something you should do in your client code, not on the database level.

However, with an additional table containing the mappings it would be possible:

```
INSERT INTO mappings (department, mapping) VALUES ('Programmer', 'IT');
INSERT INTO mappings (department, mapping) VALUES ('Admin', 'IT');
INSERT INTO mappings (department, mapping) VALUES ('Support', 'IT');

SELECT t.*, COALESCE(m.mapping, t.department) FROM table t
LEFT JOIN mappings m ON (m.department = t.department)
```

Comment: I understand your point, but I am doing it in the iReport and I have no right to modify the database to suit my needs. sigh~ Anyway, thanks for your answer. ;)